# Deadlock while inserting data to a table

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Can anyone explain how a deadlock can happen due to a bitmapped index column while inserting data in to a oracle table concurrently ?

I am aware of bitmap index locks all the rows with same bitmap key cloumn values that we are updating. But how can deadlock happen in case of insert on a table with bitmapped index?

Comment: Please read [ASK] and [mre]

Comment: Don't close this question yet; in this case, the OP would need to know the solution in order to build a reproducible example. These kind of problems are notoriously difficult to reduce to a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks happen all the time on indexes, whether bitmap or not. If the index is unique inserts of the same value will block; if non-unique, ITL slots can be unavailable and hence block. Any blocking condition can turn into a deadlock as soon as the chain becomes circular. So for example:

```
1. Process A inserts a new index entry in block 1.
2. Process B inserts a new index entry in block 2.
3. Process B tries to insert a new index entry into block 1, but there are no available ITL slots or free space to create another one, so it waits for process A to let go of its ITL slot.
4. Process A tries to insert a new index entry into block 2, but there are no available ITL slots or free space to create another one, so it waits on process B to let go of its ITL slot.
```

Bam... circular wait, deadlock. And this is just one scenario, as mentioned above, anything that cause one process to wait on another can result in deadlocking if they end up waiting on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Locks apply to Oracle indexes as well as tables. Because of the way bitmap indexes store data, a *table insert* may lead to an *index update*.

For example, in session #1, create a simple table with a bitmap index and insert one value, "A":

```
--Session #1:
create table test1(a varchar2(100));
create bitmap index test1_idx on test1(a);
insert into test1 values('A');
```

The bitmap index will look something like this:

```
Value   Bitmap
-----   ------
A       10000...
```

In session #2, insert a new value, "B":

```
--Session #2:
insert into test1 values('B');
```

The bitmap index now looks like this:

```
Value   Bitmap
-----   ------
A       10000...
B       01000...
```

In the same session #2, try to insert another row with the value "A". This row will be blocked and the session will hang. Although the table row is not blocked, think about the change to the index. This third table row needs to change the "A" bitmap index from "10000" to "10100". But the first session hasn't committed yet, so the change must wait.

```
--Session #2:
insert into test1 values('A');
... hangs ...
```

So session #2 is waiting on session #1. Now, go back to session #1 and try to insert another row for value "B". This would try to change the "B" bitmap index from "01000" to "01010". But session #2 already has that index entry locked, so now session #1 is waiting on session #2. Two sessions are waiting on each other, which means one of them must be killed to release the resources, leading to the "ORA-00060" exception.

```
--Session #1:
insert into test1 values('B');
... hangs ...

In a few seconds, session #2 will fail with:
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

This is why you want to avoid creating bitmap indexes on tables with concurrent DML.